# Hadoop Setup not working when increasing the memory allocated per node

Tags: hadoop, memory

I added the following properties to my yarn-site.xml to allocate 24 GB memory to each node.

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>24576</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>2.1</value>
</property>
```

I also added following to the mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>
```

Now my nodes do show 24 GB each of allocated memory but when I run my task lot of reduce tasks start before the mappers are done and all tasks keep failing. Most of them fail with this exception:

```
15/04/13 17:34:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1428956863444_0001_m_000028_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
```

The same process runs with default configuration of 8 GB per node. It would take couple of hours to complete but used to work. I cant even get the process to run successfully.

Is there any other config I need to change? Any help will be highly appreciated.